# AS3: Generating multiple movie clips (random locations)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, movie, flash-cs5, clip

I'm trying to generate multiple stars in the stage, but I keep getting an action script error.

```
stop();
var i;
var arrayStars:Array;
for(i=0; i<70; i++) {
    arrayStars[i] = new Star(); //Star is a linked movie clip exported to AS3.
    arrayStars[i].x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1650);
    arrayStars[i].y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1060);
    addChild(arrayStars[i]);
}
```

The error I get is:

> **TypeError: Error #1009:** Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>          at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[Untitled_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:7]
>          at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
>          at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
>          at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
>          at runtime::AppRunner/run()
>          at global/runtime::ADLEntry()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your Array.

```
var arrayStars:Array = [];
```

Or:

```
var arrayStars:Array = new Array();
```

Also, I'd be more inclined to do this:

```
var arrayStars:Array = [];

for(var i:int = 0; i<70; i++)
{
    var star:Star = new Star();

    star.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1650);
    star.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1060);

    addChild(star);
    arrayStars.push(star);
}
```